# Class def method initialize to 0?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, initialization, zero

I am trying to understand this code.

I am trying to initialize it to zero. `def seconds=()`, what does this mean?

I would have to call `def seconds` to get the variable.  Isn't this the same if I would just put `attr_accessor :seconds`?

```
require 'time'
class Timer

  def seconds=(seconds)
    @second = seconds
  end

  def seconds
    @seconds
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the same.

`attr_accessor :seconds` creates a setter and getter for the `@seconds` instance variable for you, so you don't have to do it explicitly.

Also, you misnamed `@second` in the setter.

Answer (score 1):

To auto-initialize a class variable to zero, define it and then override its reader method:

```
class Timer
  attr_accessor :seconds

  def seconds
    @seconds ||= 0
  end
end
```

Comment: Note, if he was to do this, he could also just do `attr_writer :seconds` and then write his own reader method instead of overriding it. Though, I imagine there isn't any performance gain in the choice (if there is, I'd love to hear it though)

Comment: @David: Best I'm aware, there's a tiny (negligible) performance impact due to the function getting defined twice. Still, I tend to err on the side of using `attr_accessor` regardless: it adds clarity to the class's definition if you're scanning its source for properties.